# Why "two unicorns in my backyard are eating flowers" can't be vacuous truth?

Tags: truth

**"Two unicorns in my backyard are eating flowers".**

Why can't it be vacuously true even if there are no unicorns in my backyard?

For all x, if x are two unicorns in my backyard, then x are eating flowers. Does it make sense?

I've read all of wiki but still don't know why.

Comment: How to parse it? If we rewrite it as "There are two unicorns in my backyard and they are eating flowers", it is simply False.

Comment: As per comments to your first post, in "everyday contexts" (using natural language) we seldom (never?) use vacuous true statements.

Comment: you could trick, by claiming to have no backyard... but "trick truth" can also (natural language wise) be considered as "lie" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your translation is a bit off.

> A. Two unicorns in my back yard are eating flowers.

would be translated into logic something like this:

> B. There exist x,y where x is not y and x and y are unicorns and x and y are eating flowers.

This is false because both A and B imply that x and y exist but x and y do not exist. Your translation

> C. For all x, if x are two unicorns in my backyard, then x are eating flowers.

would be rendered in normal English more like this:

> D. Every pair of unicorns in my back yard is eating flowers.

C is true because it does not imply that the pair of unicorns exists. D could be construed as true because there is no semantic implication that the unicorns exist. There is however, a pragmatic implication that the unicorns exist because it makes no sense that you would say D if there are no unicorns in your back yard, which is why a lot of native speakers would say that D is false.

BTW, adding numbers complicates things unnecessarily. It's easier to do these examples with just one object rather than n objects.

Comment: That's a great explanation! 1 misconception down, 16,734 to go...

Comment: Then, for some languages that "every pair of unicorns in my back yard is eating flowers" semantically implies there is at least one pair of unicorns, is it false in those languages?

Comment: @Faints, that's a hard question to answer because if the sentence in the other language semantically implies the existence of at least one pair of unicorns, I don't think it would be translated into English as "every pair of unicorns in my back yard is eating flowers".

Answer (score 1):

1. > "Two unicorns in my backyard are eating flower"

   is an unconditioned statement. The statement is **false**, because
   there are no unicorns in your backward, notably not two flower
   eating unicorns.
2. > "For all x, if x are two unicorns in my backyard, then x are eating
   > flowers."

   is a conditioned statement, an implication, quantified over all pairs of unicorns. The statement is **true**: Because unicorns do not exist,
   the premiss of the implication

   > in my backyard is x, a pair of unicorns  => x eats flowers

   is false, Hence - ex falso sequitur quodlibet - the implication is
   true. Hence the whole quantified statement is true, but it is  vacuous.